# PAW SetApp - "Secure Password" option missing from password fields in (Simple) Auth

Tags: paw-app

Using Paw (SetApp) latest (`v3.1.5`) and the Basic Auth headers don't have the option to turn the password field into a "Secure Dynamic Value" as mentioned on the docs in:

https://paw.cloud/docs/security/keychain

This is what the doc shows as an example:

[image: Example in Paw Docs]

This is what I get in my software:

[image: Basic Auth Field in my Paw version]

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Enable "Encryption" for the File to get this to work

[image: Enable Encryption for the file]

Playing around with the project's settings, the form field now can now be encrypted.

So it's more a doc bug than a product bug!

The password field now matches the one in the docs:

[image: Password field after Encryption is enabled]